# Super stuck on USACO Broken Necklace Problem

Tags: python

As a foreword, this problem has been asked about before. However, it's either been asked using different languages or different approaches, and I'd rather understand the problem with my code as opposed to copy-pasting the accepted solution.

---

So, for context, the problem goes something like this:

Given a string of beads like `rwbbwrbwbrwbrb`, find the maximum length of consecutive beads of one color (letter) followed by beads of the other color (letter) with the caveat that white can be counted as red or white.

For example, `wwwbbrwrbrbrrbrbrwrwwrbwrwrrb` should return 11 because you could break the necklace after `wwwbbrwrbrbrrbrbrwrwwrb`to have `wrwrrbwwwbb` (keeping in mind that a necklace loops over itself, not like a list) which would end up being `rrrrrbbbbbb` in terms of color.

My code(I've stripped all the I/O parts to simplify it) with the test case `rwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwbwrwbwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwr` of length `77`:

```py
necklace = "rwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwbwrwbwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwr"
length = 77
necklace *= 2
maxes = []
for index, bead in enumerate(necklace[0: length]):
    firstStreak = 1
    i = 1
    while i < length and (necklace[index + i] == bead or necklace[index + i] == "w"):
        i += 1
        firstStreak += 1
    secondStreak = 0
    while i < length and necklace[index + i] != bead:
        i += 1
        secondStreak += 1
    maxes.append(firstStreak + secondStreak)
print(max(maxes))
```

This outputs 73, and the correct answer is 74.

This code did work on the two prior test cases (`wwwbbrwrbrbrrbrbrwrwwrbwrwrrb` and `rrr`)

I'd also appreciate any feedback on best practices/structure that I didn't follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to deal with the case when you start looking at a "w". My solution to this would be to start counting anyway and decide what it should be when you encounter the next non-w in the loop

```
necklace = "rwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwbwrwbwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwrwr"
length = len(necklace)
necklace *= 2
maxes = []
for index, bead in enumerate(necklace[0: length]):
    firstStreak = 1
    i = 1
    while i < length and necklace[index + i] == bead or necklace[index + i] == "w" or bead == "w":
        if (bead == "w") and (necklace[index + i] != "w") :
            bead = necklace[index + i]
        i += 1
        firstStreak += 1
    secondStreak = 0
    while i < length and (necklace[index + i] != bead):
        i += 1
        secondStreak += 1
    maxes.append(firstStreak + secondStreak)
print(max(maxes))
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Retraction**: Alistair's answer is better & this program still doesn't account for starting on a w

Never mind, I solved it. The solution was to also iterate over the list *backwards*. Here was my complete implementation

```py
fin = open('beads.in', 'r')
lineList = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in fin]
fout = open('beads.out', 'w')
necklace = lineList[1]
length = int(lineList[0])
necklace *= 3
maxes = []
for index, bead in enumerate(necklace[0: length]):
    firstStreak = 1
    i = 1
    while i < length and (necklace[index + i] == bead or necklace[index + i] == "w"):
        i += 1
        firstStreak += 1
    secondStreak = 0
    while i < length and necklace[index + i] != bead:
        i += 1
        secondStreak += 1
    maxes.append(firstStreak + secondStreak)

for index, bead in enumerate(reversed(necklace[length: length * 2])):
    firstStreak = 0
    i = 1
    while i < length and (necklace[index + i] == bead or necklace[index + i] == "w"):
        i += 1
        firstStreak += 1
    secondStreak = 0
    while i < length and necklace[index + i] != bead:
        i += 1
        secondStreak += 1
    maxes.append(firstStreak + secondStreak)
fout.write(str(max(maxes)) + '\n')
```

Comment: Interesting, I think I found a way to do it in the single loop

Comment: Glad to help. Fun problem